# Why is no-one approving my edit. which was requested?

Tags: discussion, editing

Why is no-one approving my edit. which was requested?

It takes a few people, I guess, but I imagine it can be done in about 12 concerted clicks, which alone anyway I can do in a few seconds. It's frustrating, it's important to me, and I can't see why it would be important to anyone not to ***make those clicks happen***.

[Can a point divide two lines?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/45768/can-a-point-divide-two-lines)

Cheers.

Comment: I think that if you didn't consistently delete your account and then remake multiple accounts, ask questions on them and then change to a further different account to try to edit them, if you didn't do all of that and instead just used one account, these issues wouldn't happen. Your business is your business and you can do whatever you want, but this isn't the first time you've had this issue with not being able to edit a question you asked on a different throw away account after deleting your old one. It seems like it'd be easier to just not do what you're doing.

Comment: @Not_Here ha yea fair point, sorry man

Comment: just a note, to say @Not_Here i think preferable to the management to go and not come back. cheers !! L

Answer (score 3):

Are you the original author of the question? It was posted by a different account. You can always instantly edit your own posts, of course.

If that's the case you should ask to have the accounts merged through the "contact us" link at the bottom of the page.

Comment: thanks for the answer that doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @LUKE your edit does not get approved because it changes too much. Such changes are only allowed for the original author.

Comment: and yet the edit was also closed for being a duplicate! ha

Comment: @LUKE I closed your newly posted question because it *is* a duplicate of the original question. As mentioned before, you should get your accounts merged.

Comment: ah ok sorry i misunderstood your comment!

Comment: Keelan, how am i going to get my question answered? I have honed down what I meant to ask, which if any question should I edit?

Comment: @LUKE you should take what several people have told you now seriously. Read my answer closely, it already says what you should do to get your question reopened. Read Not_Here's comment above, it tells you what you should do to prevent this from happening again.

Comment: ok, thank you for taking the time to reply

Answer (score -1):

it doesn't matter at all, becasue, due to no-one approving the edit, I can just repost the question.

Great!

Comment: That's not really how this works.